# How to preview variable in automations with shortcuts in HomeKit?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app, homekit

I simply have the following shortcut:

[image]
[image]

and here `Łazienka Love` is called at the end. I dont know why. Should be called `Łazienka Noc`. Why `#counter` is not equal to 11?

Comment: I feel we're missing some info here. Because i don't speak Polish, Google tells me the three are Bathroom Day, Night & .. ermm … Love. but I'm sure it's not making up its own titles, so how did you get Love into the list & why can't you change it to Night? and… is that supposed to be a dwell timer structure? It looks a bit awkward, not that I'm any shortcuts expert. Also, if you're not == 11, then do nothing. An `if` doesn't need an `else`

Comment: If you just want a 100s dwell, why not just `wait 100s`, then flip your `set`?

Comment: Łazienka Love is Bathroom Love (because then pink lights are turned on);) It doesnt matter here... you are right;) I should simplify my example first...

Comment: Of course you are right about wait 100s... but I rather think why it is not eleven, when it should... I am learning shortcuts on my examples;) So it might not be useful... maybe there is indeed simpler and smarted way to do the same... but I would like to understand this complicated example. Will you help me?;)

Comment: @Tetsujin one more thing. My motion sensor detects motion before my 100 seconds loop end. Then my shortcut is triggered before the first one finished. And now the question: Is my variable value shared between two calls of my shortcut? Becauee if every shourtcut must be completed, and variables are shared between calls.. then the first one will not turn off the lights because his shared variable is resetted and never will be 11. It will not work in case when I have true/false. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: I've never used Shortcuts, so I don't know the available options.. I can work 'pseudo-code' based on other [rather primitive] languages so at one time I was not bad at making things do what the language didn't offer directly. This, though breaks down to `Set day; wait 100; set night;` The rest seems to be redundant.

Comment: If you have a global variable, then you can use it as a binary switch. 0 or 1 [which is often auto-coerced to be TRUE/FALSE] `If FALSE (go round again); else return();` If you want this variable to make another function wait, then set `1` at the head & set back to `0` as you exit. You can make `if FALSE` into a `while` loop or a `do while` loop, depending on how you need to return at the end. Your `counter` only ever returns a valid value once. You'd do better to use `>=` rather than just `=` so you don't miss it if your independant threads don't sync.

Comment: i'm actually struggling to see how you can implement a dwell timer unless you can generate a timestamped 'last' value. I've run right out of Shortcuts talent at this point ;) I've used dwell timers a lot in simple languages, but I don't have the language chops for Shortcuts. Sorry :\

Comment: I really appreciate your help and basic explanation;) But here it works a little different way... It look like kind of programming, but it is not..;) I actually do not understand how it works. It is never explained, and no docs from Apple;)